# Code Syntax Highlighting in KeystoneJS TinyMCE Editor

Tags: javascript, tinymce, keystonejs

I'm attempting to install a the ["codesample" TinyMCE plugin](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/plugins/codesample/) to enable code syntax highlighting in Keystone.js.  I added the following line to the keystone.init section of the keystone.js file [per the documentation](http://keystonejs.com/docs/configuration/#options-ui).  However, no extra button to enable syntax highlighting appears.

```
'wysiwyg additional plugins': 'codesample',
'wysiwyg additional options': {
        external_plugins: {
            'codesample':'/js/tinymce/plugin.min.js'
       }
```

The plugin documentation says that a code highlight button is included as part of the plugin. Since the button did not show up I attempted to force it by adding the following line.

```
'wysiwyg additional buttons': 'codesample',
```

No errors are showing up on the console.  I'd appreciate any help in getting this or some other form of code syntax highlighting working with KeystoneJS.

Comment: Did you ever get a solution for this?

Comment: No, I never did.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the plugin included with TinyMCE working by putting this in your keystone.init function:

```
'wysiwyg additional plugins': 'codesample',
'wysiwyg additional buttons': 'codesample',
```

But when I did this, although it got it working, it seemed like you can create code samples, but not edit them, unless you delete & remake them.  I tried replacing the TinyMCE version included with keystone (majorVersion:"4",minorVersion:"4.3") with a newer one, as 5.2 and beyond claims to have fixed this issue, but it didn't do me any good.

Perhaps you'd have better luck installing the plugin this way, treating it as an external plugin:

```
'wysiwyg additional options': {
        skin : 'lightgray',
        menubar : 'file edit format view insert',
        relative_urls: false,
        content_css: '/assets/css/styles.min.css',
        visualblocks_default_state: true,
        external_plugins: {
            'tinyvision':'/assets/plugins/tinyvision/build/plugin.min.js'
        },
        tinyvision: {
            source: '/api/images'
        }
}
```

Reference: https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone/issues/1549

Slightly less useful reference: http://keystonejs.com/docs/configuration/#options-ui